# How to pass values for password_reset() in Django 1.10?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I would like to pass the url value post_reset_redirect to Django. I have an url.py with appname = polls, so I want to pass it to avoid `No reverse match` error

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset(post_reset_redirect='polls:password_reset_done'),
        name='password_reset'),
```

But I have the error:

```
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

How to pass values for password_reset() in Django 1.10?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the error:

```
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, {'post_reset_redirect':'polls:password_reset_done'},
        name='password_reset'),
```